# Read JSON format with Swift 4

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I used parse get a list of a class 'Score',
here is one element of the list.
It is a PFObject object

```
> <Score: 0x1c02a84c0, objectId: vcLqhvw0JP, localId: (null)> {
>     ACL = "<PFACL: 0x1c0223c00>";
>     score = 888;
>     username = asd; }
```

How can I get the username and score, instead of the objectID and localID?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a object that will hold this `json` so you need to call like this this:

> Here `yourobject` is a object that is holding your Score class response:

```
let score = yourObject["score"]
let userName = yourObject["username"]
```